# Property Scope in PHP Classes

Tags: php, class, methods, properties, scope

### What I Need

Ability to access prop `$result`, defined inside of method `fill_default_values`, inside of method `html`.

### Summary

I have two methods, `fill_default_values` and `html` inside of a class `Admin`. I'm having trouble getting access to a prop, `$result`, from inside of `fill_default_values` when calling it inside of `html`.

### Code

### **`fill_default_values`**

```
  // grabs values from DB and fills inputs on ADMIN PAGE
  protected static function fill_default_values() {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'bb_slidersettings';
    $result = $wpdb->get_results(
      "SELECT
       id
       FROM
       $table_name;"
    );

    if (!$result) {
    ?>

      <small class="text-red">Something went wrong</small>

    <?php
    } // endif

    return $result;
  }// fill_default_values()
```

### **`html`**

```
  // Outputs HTML to main admin page
  public static function html() {
    self::fill_default_values();

    ?>

    <!-- BEGIN HTML -->
    <form id="bb-carousel-form" action="" method="POST">
      <input name="carousel_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result[0]->id; ?>">
  }
```

You can see that I create the `fill_default_values` method and call it from inside of `html` where I would expect `$result` to be available. Instead I get this error message.

### **`error`**

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: result in <b>[FILE PATH]</b> on line <b>120</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in <b>[FILE PATH]</b> on line <b>120</b><br />
```

Oddly enough, if I were to move the entirety of `fill_default_values` into `html` everything works like a charm.

Comment: So where do you think `$result` is going to be magic'd up from

Comment: Maybe is you did `$result = self::fill_default_values();`

Comment: I thought if I returned it then I would be able to access it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly `$result = self::fill_default_values();` did the trick. Go ahead and answer if you want some credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the returned value like this

```
$result = self::fill_default_values();
```

Then `$result` should have a value